# Alamofire Xcode 7 beta 5

Tags: alamofire, xcode7-beta5

I've installed Alamofire in my project several times and it still doesn't work.
I tried with cocoa pods and manually, but same result, "import Alamofire" gives an error

> No such module Alamofire

Please help ! :)

Comment: Are you using Objective-C or Swift?

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the following for us to assist you further:

- Your `Podfile`
- Output of `pod --version`
- Output of `xcodebuild -version`

> The issue certainly lies somewhere in one of those outputs.

Until you post them, here are a few suggestions:

- You need to use Alamofire 2.0.0-beta.1 if you are running Xcode 7 beta 5.

  - If you are running beta 6, upgrade to Alamofire 2.0.0-beta.3.
- You need to use CocoaPods 0.38.2
- You need to have the correct command line tools set which you can find in your Xcode `Preferences` => `Locations` => `Command Line Tools`.

  - Make sure that is set to your preferred version of Xcode.

> I'll update my answer accordingly once you update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try do the following:

1. Product -> Clean
2. Product -> Build

failing that you should check your build configuration.